# Are there any programs other than NFS that use the Network Status Monitor protocol / rpc.statd?

Tags: freebsd, nfs

I'm running a FreeBSD server, and I'd really like to get rid of some extra fluff. In particular, I'm absolutely sure that I won't be running an NFS client or server. I know that I can remove the NFS daemon and kernel module as well as rpc.lockd, but I'm not sure about rpc.statd. As far as I'm aware NFS/NLM is the only program that uses statd, but I know that the NSM protocol is designed to be general purpose, and I don't want to delete it if something else might rely on it.

Does anyone know of a program besides NFS/NLM (rpc.lockd) that uses NSM (rpc.statd)?

Thanks,

--Dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You can ditch all the rpc.* servers and anything else that registers with rpcbind. Also, rpcbind itself. Setting `nfs_server_enable="NO"` and `rpcbind_enable="NO"` in `/etc/rc.conf` should do it.